# Only allow number to be entered once in input

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, validation, input

Is there any way of using javascript/jquery to prevent a user entering the same number twice in an input box?  The user can enter as many numbers as they want (one at a time), but I need to alert the user/take other action if they try to enter the same number a second time.  I have tried creating an array:

```
 function history() {
 var numbers = [];
 numbers.push(document.getElementById('inputBox').value);
 }
```

and then running:

```
 var n = document.getElementById('inputBox').value;
 if ($.inArray(n, numbers)> -1) {
   // alert, do something
 }
```

but the new array ('numbers') never gets populated by the user input, so the if clause never fires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps? I assume you are using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) because of the [`$.inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) in your code.

```
var numbers = [];
$('#inputBox').change(function () {
    if ($.inArray($(this).val(), numbers)) {
        // Alert the user/take other action
    } else {
        // Otherwise, add it to the array of numbers
        numbers.push($(this).val());
    }
});
```

It would be better if there was a button the user had to click to add the new number. Otherwise, it will be quite annoying.

Comment: This works with a few small changes- `$('#inputBox').keypress(function(event) {
  if(event.keyCode ==13) {
    if ($.inArray($(this).val(), numbers)> -1) {`  Without the `> -1` the alert triggered on the first entry of a number.  Now it's fine.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `numbers` variable is scoped to the `history()` function, so the `numbers` variable instanced that is being set is only accessibly by the `history()` function. This code will accomplish what you're trying to do without a global `numbers` variable and prevents any duplicate numbers from being entered by intercepting and canceling the key event.

```
$("#inputBox").on("keydown", function(e) {
    var numbers = $(this).val();
    var c = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
    return ~numbers.indexOf(c);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the really quick reply - but it still fails.  If I run `alert('' + names + '')` immediately after the if check, it's empty.